# How do I sent files from Ubuntu to windows via terminal?

Tags: 16.04, networking, scp

I want to sent files over a private network from Ubuntu 16.04 to a windows box.(Its an IOT box) I am able to scp into other linux devices but how do I send files to windows? I want to do this via terminal? As I am building a console application. I want to do this entirely from the Ubuntu ask the windows box is remote.
Thanks.

Comment: Reading "windows box" I assume you are in some kind of virtual environment? Could you add it to the description and the title so people know what it is about?

Comment: Its not a virtual environment. It is an iot box

Comment: @mikewhatever: Could you please explain how that would enable OP to copy files from a *local* Ubuntu machine to a *remote* Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

If the windows disk is mounted in Nautilus, it probably have the path at /run/gvfs/user/1000/ etc., and using such path should work. If my path is wrong, is something similar, Google for the right one.

Maybe need to install DEB package Samba server/client and also verify setup at app "personal file sharing".